# ASP.NET MVC change session and application cookie domain name to View names/custom names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to change the way my application sets domain names for cookies.

1. I'm trying to get cookies used by a View to use the View name as the domain name for a cookie.
   Is there a way I could do that through configuration rather than custom coding for Views individually.

2.
Can I force my session/auth cookies to use custom domain name?
Forms auth uses name from config to as the cookie name, but does not let you choose a custom domain name.
e.g.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="forms" [domain=".test.com" ???] loginUrl="/Index" timeout="120"  slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What is reason for this?

Comment: For security reasons. So that the same cookie (with a same domain name) cannot be used to request another view/page in the same server/application.